# Background Audio stops once WP8 App has been minimized and then resumed

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app, there is a background audio that plays **throughout my App.**

When *I minimize the App,* the **audio obviously goes off** as it is supposed to do. However, when *I resume the app,* the audio does not continue, that is **totally stops!**

Another interesting thing to be noted in my App is that **after resuming**, *only the background music is affected whereas other audio that need to be played for a short duration, say for example on a button click, function normally as expected.*

I think it's got something to do with the App's life cycle and Fast App Resume feature.

Kindly help me out. Thanks.

Comment: What is your app actually doing? Is it using MediaElement, or XNA MediaPlayer, or Media Foundation, or something else?

Comment: See, my app basically has a background music, to make it clear the background music is nothing more than a simple audio file that is looped through out my app.

For this I am using a simple MediaElement control.

To play other types of "short interval sounds" I am using the SoundEffect class, that is the XNA Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not working on with the `BackgroundAudioPlayer`, then you should check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in order to play `Background Audio` within your application.

Reference: [Background Audio Streamer Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb)

Comment: See, I doubt the thing that you've mentioned is what I require. 

Take the example for a WP8 game say, Temple Run/Subway Surfer. While playing the game you've got the upbeat background music playing. As soon as you minimize the game, the sound goes off.

 Cool till here.

Now when you resume your game, the music continues in games I mentioned before. However, this does not happen in my case.

Comment: @AnmolKumar So what you want is to keep on playing the music whether your app is resumed or not?

Comment: To sum it up here's what I want.

My app plays background music while the user is operating/using my app. **(Check, already satisfies)** The background music should pause/stop when the user navigates away from my app that is minimizes it. **(Check, already satisfies)** The background music should resume/start playing when the user resumes using my app that is my app is no longer minimized. **(Oops! This point goes wrong!)**